# How to implement intersection type with overrides

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop

I am creating a control manager that will be an abstract base for other control managers: ButtonManager, InputManager, PopupManager, etc. The controls share some similarity but not all. For instance, size and intent. I want to define shared types in ControlManager as well as an interface in ControlManager that uses these types.

All controls will have an intent, but not all controls will have the same set of intents, as the base set can be added to. I want to be able to create a base ControlIntent type in the abstract ControlManager class and extend it in derived classes.

I should note that I have ControlManager as an abstract class because I would like to enforce classes that implement ControlManager to define certain functionality such as setIntentClass, setSizeClass, etc

The control manager defines a type ControlIntent as

```
export type ControlIntent = 'Default' | 'Disabled'
```

ButtonManager that extends ControlManager then defines its intent type as

```
export type ButtonIntent = ControlManager.ControlIntent & 'Secondary' | 'Success' | 'Warning' | 'Danger'
```

The interface in ControlManager defines some shared options. Using intent as an example:

```
export interface IOptions {
  controlIntent: ControlIntent
}
```

Then in ButtonManager I want to extend the options interface and override the intent property:

```
export interface IOptions extends ControlManager.IOptions {
  controlIntent: ButtonIntent
}
```

Potentially I am missing the big picture, but it seems to me that I should be able to enforce my implemented control managers to have a size and intent with at least the typed options defined in the base class. 'Default' and 'Disabled' for intent, but be able to add new intents in the extended interfaces without having to create a new property.

To summarize:

All controls have a size and intent with at least a minimal set of predefined options. I can then use intersection in the different control managers to add to the predefined options, but would like to be able to define said options in the base interface and then extend them in derived interfaces.

Is this a practical design decision, and if so, how do I accomplish it? Many thanks to all contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "adding options" what you're doing is *widening* the type, not *extending* it.  Extending is always a narrowing operation (placing more restrictions).  So you want a union, not an intersection... if you try to intersect two types with no overlap, you get an empty type equivalent to `never` (sometimes the compiler will actually collapse the type to `never` and other times it will keep the intersection around but you will find you can't assign any useful values to it):

```
type ControlIntent = 'Default' | 'Disabled'

// note the parentheses I added because the operators don't have the precedence you think
type ButtonIntent = ControlIntent & ('Secondary' | 'Success' | 'Warning' | 'Danger') // oops
// check with IntelliSense:  type Button = never
```

So the type you presumably mean is this:

```
type ControlIntent = 'Default' | 'Disabled'
type ButtonIntent = ControlIntent | ('Secondary' | 'Success' | 'Warning' | 'Danger') 
// type ButtonIntent = "Default" | "Disabled" | "Secondary" | "Success" | "Warning" | "Danger"
```

---

That's great but the confusion between narrowing/extends/intersection and widening/super/union persists into your interfaces.  The following definition (I'm changing the name to `IButtonOptions` so it can sit in the same namespace as `IOptions`) now becomes an error:

```
export interface IOptions {
  controlIntent: ControlIntent
}

export interface IButtonOptions extends IOptions { // error!
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// Interface 'IButtonOptions' incorrectly extends interface 'IOptions'.
  controlIntent: ButtonIntent
}
```

That's because `IButtonOptions` violates an important [substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if `IButtonOptions` extends `IOptions`, then an `IButtonOptions` object *is* an `IOptions` object.  Meaning that if you ask for an `IOptions` object, I can give you an `IButtonOptions` object and you will be happy.  But since you asked for an `IOptions` object, you expect its `controlIntent` property to be `'Default'` or `'Disabled'`.  You would be rightfully unhappy with me if your supposed `IOptions` object turned out to have some other value for `controlIntent`.  You'd look at it, and say, "wait, what's this `"Secondary"` string here?

---

So you need to redesign your interfaces for this to work.  You'll have to give up on the idea of `IButtonOptions` being a subtype of `IOptions`.  Instead, you might consider making `IOptions` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type where the type of the `controlIntent` property can be specified by the generic parameter.  Perhaps like this:

```
export interface IOptions<I extends string = never> {
  controlIntent: ControlIntent | I;
}

export interface IButtonOptions extends IOptions<ButtonIntent> {
  // don't even need to specify controlIntent here
}

const bo: IButtonOptions = {
    controlIntent: "Success";
} // okay
```

So the `I` parameter must be assignable to `string` and it [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `never`, so that the type `IOptions` without a parameter specified is the same type as your original `IOptions`.

But now, `IButtonOptions` does not extend `IOptions`, but instead it extends `IOptions<ButtonIntent>`.  Then everything works.

Keep in mind that if you do this, functions that used to expect an `IOptions` object parameter will now also have to be made generic:

```
function acceptOptionsBroken(options: IOptions) {}
acceptOptionsBroken(bo); // oops, error
//                  ~~ 
// Argument of type 'IButtonOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IOptions<never>'.
```

---

Okay, hope that helps you proceed.  Good luck!

```
function acceptOptions<I extends string>(options: IOptions<I>) {}
acceptOptions(bo); // okay, I is inferred as "Secondary" | "Success" | "Warning" | "Danger"
```